# Best practice for bundling third party libraries for distribution in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dependencies, software-distribution

I'm developing an application using Python 3.  What is the best practice to use third party libraries for development process and end-user distribution?  Note that I'm working within these constraints:

- Developers in the team should have the exact same version of the libraries.
- An ideal solution would work on both Windows and Linux.
- I would like to avoid making the user install software before using our own; that is, they shouldn't have to install product A and product B before using ours.

Comment: I've had this problem show up. I was building a raytracer with Python, and I relied on PIL to write images. It completely broke my raytracer when I moved it over to a Mac, as Apple doesn't ship PIL with Mac OS. If you don't use the library much, consider getting rid of it and write your own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no best practices, but there are a few different tracks people follow.  With regard to *commercial* product distribution there are the following:

**Manage Your Own Package Server**

With regard to your development process, it is typical to either have your dev boxes update from a local package server.  That allows you to "freeze" the dependency list (i.e. just stop getting upstream updates) so that everyone is on the same version.  You can update at particular times and have the developers update as well, keeping everyone in lockstep.

For customer installs you usually write an install script. You can collect all the packages and install your libs, as well as the other at the same time.  There can be issues with trying to install a new Python, or even any standard library because the customer may already depend on a different version.  Usually you can install in a sandbox to separate your packages from the systems packages.  This is more of a problem on Linux than Windows.

**Toolchain**

The other option is to create a toolchain for each supported OS.  A toolchain is all the dependencies (up to, but not including base OS libs like `glibc`).  This toolchain gets packaged up and distributed for both developers *AND* customers.  Best practice for a toolchain is:

- change the executable to prevent confusion. (ie. python -> pkg_python)
- don't install in `.../bin` directories to prevent accidental usage. (ie. on Linux you can install under `.../libexec`.  `/opt` is also used although personally I detest it.)
- install your libs in the correct location under `lib/python/site-packages` so you don't have to use PYTHONPATH.
- Distribute the source `.py` files for the executables so the install script can relocate them appropriately.
- The package format should be an OS native package (RedHat -> RPM, Debian -> DEB, Win -> MSI)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) to create egg files for your libraries, assuming they aren't available in egg form already.  You could then bundle the eggs alongside your software, which would need to either install them, or ensure that they were on the import path.

This has some complexities, i.e. if your libraries have C-extensions, then your eggs become platform-specific, but in my experience this is the most widely-accepted means of 'bundling' stuff in Python.

I have to say that this remains one of Python's weaknesses, though; the third-party ecosystem is certainly aimed at developers rather than end-users.

Comment: highly agree with your end-user weakness remark. Im finding a lot of trouble coming up with a clean systematic way to build software tools and pipeline that makes little fuss for windows-based end users when handing over the software to them.

Answer (score 1):

- For developers use [PIP](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) with [requirements file](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/#requirements-files).
- For end users, specify requirements in [setup.py](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html).

Comment: Well, thanks, but it is violates #1, #3 from my list. Assuming that there is no internet connection for client. And developers should always take fixed version from (??? may be SVN repository)

Comment: I would advise against putting 3rd party modules into your own SVN repository especially if you're developing and testing cross platform as they will need to be compiled differently. As for @vartec's suggestion not meeting your requirements I think you're mistaken. A requirements file can specify a module and a version for that module, so meets your requirements exactly. Also make sure you're not violating any license terms if you embed other projects inside your own project.

Comment: @StephenPaulger - our project is distributed as source, so no violation to include another LGPL library sources. You have caught main things ow my question but it still opened. What is the correct technical solution to embed 3d party?

Comment: @Dewfy: it doesn't violate #1, as both in requirements file, as in setup.py you might specify **exact** version. For installing w/o connection, it is possible to tell distutils to use local repository